# c language, global symbol, local symbol clarification

Tags: c

Given the following c code

```
static int x = 0;

int what_is_this(void) {
    static int y = 5;
    x = x + y;
    y = y + 1;
    return y;
}

int main(void) {
    int v = what_is_this();
    printf("%d\n", v);
    return v;
}
```

With respect to the linker, is `what_is_this` a global symbol?

Is `x` a local symbol?

Is `v` not registered as a symbol?

Answer (score 2):

As per here: https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~xianeizhang/notes/Linking.html#symbol

> - global: global symbols that are defined by module m and that can be referenced by other modules. Global linker symbols correspond to
>     nonstatic funcs and global vars that are defined without the static
>     attribute.
> - external: global symbols that are referenced by module m but defined by some other module. Such symbols are called externals and
>     correspond to funcs and vars that are defined in other modules.
> - local (static): local symbols that are defined and referenced exclusively by module m. Some local linker symbols correspond funcs
>     and global vars that are defined with the static attribute. These
>     symbols are visible anywhere within module m, but cannot be referenced
>     by other modules.

So in simple terms global symbols are non-static,non-extern functions, and non-static, non-extern vars, external symbol are declared with extern, and local symbols are static.

> With respect to the linker, is what_is_this a global symbol?

Not extern, not static, so yes

> Is x a local symbol?

Declared with a static, so yes

> Is v not registered as a symbol?

The linker never sees local variable declarations.(outside of maybe static variables declared in a function.)

Comment: Regarding the last question, so `v` is not registered as a symbol, since the linker never sees local variable declarations. Is this correct?